# There is a bug in div collapse

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to make a div collapse which is consists of a `select2` box. The code is as bellow:

```
<div>
    <fieldset class="majorpoints">
    <label for="ilocation">Select your location:</label><br>

    <div >
        <div class="hider" style="display:none">
            {{ wizard.form.location }}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and a jQuery code:

```
<script>
    $('.majorpoints').click(function(){
    $(this).find('.hider').toggle();
    });  
</script>
```

But there is bug that after opening the div, once I want to write in the select2 box, div get closed. I don't know if there is solution to skip this bug!!

*When collapsed, and before click again*

[image]

*When collapsed, and after click again*

[image]

This the rendered code:

[image]

Comment: its because you have added an click event for the parent element fieldset which contains the select2, which means initial state is hidden once you toggled the child visibility you start to click the select2 to search something again click event triggered which toggle the visibility state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can workaround this by checking if the current clicked target is the selectinput otherwise toggle display :

```
if(!$(e.target).hasClass("hider")) // perform toggle;
```

also you have to stop event propagation on the `.hider` div so , it stop bubbling event from to parent dom nodes by adding :

```
$('.hider').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

see Snippet below :

```js
$(function() {
  
  
  $('.majorpoints').click(function(e) {
    var $target = $(e.target);
    if(!$target.hasClass("hider"))
      $(this).find('.hider').toggle();
  });
  
  $('.hider').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <fieldset class="majorpoints">
    <label for="ilocation">Select your location:</label><br>

    <div>
      <div class="hider" style="display:none">
        <select>
          <option>select</option>
          <option>val 0</option>
          <option>val 1</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</div>

<script>
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but still does not work, just added some screenshot maybe could be helpful!

Comment: @J2015 check the answer , forgot to prevent event propagation